# Adding Macros to Excel multi seelct in rails

Tags: ruby, excel, vba

I wanted to use multi select list in the excel. hope the excel should contain vb macros for that. So I am trying to add the macros to the excel dynamically via ruby. But I didt get any idea. Is there any other option to generate the excel with single and multi select list option in ruby on rails.

I am using ubuntu and the libreoffice. I have manually tried to add the macro vb script in the excel in windows and it was working. But I cant do it with ruby. Please suggest if any other solutions are there

Comment: Hi, if you could edit your post to include any code you have already tried we can better help you find your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'writeexcel'
@data_array = ["option","aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","fff","ggg"]
workbook  = WriteExcel.new('single_select_dropdown.xls')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('sheet1')
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 30)
worksheet.set_column('B:B', 30)
worksheet.set_column('C:C', 20)
worksheet.set_column('A:D', 30)
worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Select Your Option')
worksheet.write(0, 1, 'option')
worksheet.data_validation(0, 1,
    {
      :validate        => 'list',
      :source          => @data_array
    })

worksheet.write(10, 2, "Your option is")
worksheet.write(10, 3, "=B1")
workbook.close
```

and this is for single select dynamic list via ruby, and still am trying multi select list

Answer (score 0):

```
require "rubygems"

require 'write_xlsx'

@data_array = ["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","fff","ggg"]

workbook  = WriteXLSX.new('multiple_select_vba_project.xlsm')

workbook.set_vba_name('Workbook')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet 
worksheet.set_vba_name('Sheet1')

worksheet.activate() #don't forgot to add this

worksheet.set_column('A:A', 30)
worksheet.set_column('C:C', 30)

workbook.add_vba_project('vbaProject.bin')

worksheet.write(1, 0, 'select your option')
worksheet.write(1, 2, 'option')
worksheet.data_validation(1, 2,
    {
      :validate        => 'list',
      :source          => @data_array 
    })

workbook.close
```

also you need vbaProject.bin file..
need to extract vbaProject.bin file from existing xls file use this command

```
   extract_vba filename.xlsm
```

if suppose got any error please update your libexcel-writer-xlsx-perl gem using this command

```
  sudo apt-get -f install
```